# Cross reference between azure sql data ware houses

Tags: azure, azure-sql, data-warehouse

In one sql server instance, I have below 2 data warehouses,

sqlwarehouse1

sqlwarehouse2

And in sqlwarehouse2, I have the table "dbo.test". How can I refer this table from sqlwarehouse1? Is this cross data warehouse communication is possible in Azure SQL ware house?

Answer (score 0):

At this moment cross database queries between Azure SQL Data Warehouse databases are not supported. This can be confirmed on the answer provided on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6dd41f99-18a9-43c7-bf45-957395a11ed7/joins-between-azure-sql-and-datawarehouse) forum thread.